# Support for en_150 locale

Tags: locale

I read at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/why-is-there-no-euro-english-locale about en_150 locale. It is also mentioned here http://cldr.unicode.org/index/downloads/cldr-22

Does Ubuntu support it? If not then when will it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It will probably be supported if/when it's included in glibc.

The `en_DK.UTF-8` locale currently serves a similar purpose, so I would guess that you can achieve basically the same settings this way:

- Select **English (Denmark)** in the *Regional Formats* tab in [Language Support](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/session-formats.html).
- Add this line to your `~/.profile` file:

  export LC_MONETARY=en_IE.UTF-8